# Jupyter Interface with GCP Dataproc backed by GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to create a GKE backed cluster in GCP Dataproc. For Compute Engine backed Dataproc clusters, there is an option to enable Web Interfaces and get access to Jupyter environment. However, I cannot seem to find Web Interface option while creating GKE backed Dataproc cluster nor can find any documentation about it.

Is there some architectural/design limitation for this or this is simply not supported right now?

Comment: Hey, did you find a way to do this? I'm also struggling.

Comment: No, had to change the problem statement and limited application to CE backed cluster for the time being.

Comment: Me too. Perhaps they still don't have support for that. Thanks for the reply. All the best.